# count new values per date per group

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, aggregation

Imagine I have following dataset

```
Date      Group    Value
01-01-19  A        X
01-01-19  A        Y
01-01-19  A        Z
02-01-19  A        X
02-01-19  A        Y
02-01-19  A        Z
02-01-19  A        W
01-01-19  B        X
01-01-19  B        Y
01-01-19  B        Z
02-01-19  B        X
02-01-19  B        X
02-01-19  B        Z
02-01-19  B        V
```

So there are two groups and two dates. I want to see per group and per date which values are new.

The resulting dataframe should look something like this

```
group    date      new_values
A        01-01-19  3 
A        02-01-19  1
B        01-01-19  3
B        02-01-19  1
```

Eventually I just counted the number of values per date per group and took the difference. But this does not take into account values that have disapeared since the previous date. I have no clue how to do this. Perhaps the `data.table` package can bring release

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rowid function counts appearances of a combination of columns, starting from 1:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DT)

DT[, new := rowid(Group, Value) == 1L]
DT[, .(n_new = sum(new)), by=.(Group, Date)]
#    Group     Date n_new
# 1:     A 01-01-19     3
# 2:     A 02-01-19     1
# 3:     B 01-01-19     3
# 4:     B 02-01-19     1
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  arrange(Date = as.Date(Date, "%d-%m-%y")) %>%
  group_by(Group, Value) %>%
  mutate(New = row_number()) %>%
  group_by(Group, Date) %>%
  summarise(New = sum(New == 1))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   Group [2]
  Group Date       New
  <fct> <fct>    <int>
1 A     01-01-19     3
2 A     02-01-19     1
3 B     01-01-19     3
4 B     02-01-19     1
```

The above assumes that your date is in the format of `day-month-year`; if this is not the case, you just change `"%d-%m-%y"` to `"%m-%d-%y"`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr` we can first `group_by` `Group` and create a column (`orig`)  which would be `TRUE` if it is seen for the first time in the group. We then `group_by` `Group` and `Date` and count the number of such original values.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  mutate(orig = !duplicated(Value)) %>%
  group_by(Group, Date) %>%
  summarise(new_values = sum(orig))

#  Group     Date     new_values
#   <fct> <fct>         <int>
#1   A     01-01-19          3
#2   A     02-01-19          1
#3   B     01-01-19          3
#4   B     02-01-19          1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(read.table(text="
01-01-19,A,X
01-01-19,A,Y
01-01-19,A,Z
02-01-19,A,X
02-01-19,A,Y
02-01-19,A,Z
02-01-19,A,W
01-01-19,B,X
01-01-19,B,Y
01-01-19,B,Z
02-01-19,B,X
02-01-19,B,X
02-01-19,B,Z
02-01-19,B,V
",sep=",",strip.white = TRUE))

setnames(dt,c("date","group","value"))
```

One solution would be to find the unique values by group. Then sum the unique values by group and date.

```
##     > dt[,dup:=!duplicated(value),.(group)][,sum(dup),.(group,date)]
## group     date V1
## 1:     A 01-01-19  3
## 2:     A 02-01-19  1
## 3:     B 01-01-19  3
## 4:     B 02-01-19  1
```